# Unable to replace form input value with Javascipt and/or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know it seems basic, but hear me out, I've been trying to figure it out for a good chunk of the day and something just isn't working.

I'm trying to replace the value of a hidden form field with the visitors IP address. This is the field in question:

```
    <label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-106493013">ipaddress:</label>
    <div class="af-textWrap"><input type="text" id="awf_field-106493013" class="text" name="custom ipaddress" value=""  onfocus=" if (this.value == '') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='';} " tabindex="503" /></div>
```

And this is the code I have on my page currently:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function getUrlParam(name, url) {
            if (!url) url = window.location.href;
            name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
            var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
                results = regex.exec(url);
            if (!results) return null;
            if (!results[2]) return '';
            return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
        }



        var tid = getUrlParam("adid");
            var date = Date(Date.now());
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
           (function (){  
             jQuery.ajax({
                   async: false,
                   type: 'GET',
                   url: 'https://api.ipify.org/?format=json',
                   success: function(data) {
                        //callback
                     console.log(data.ip) //This works properly;
                            jQuery('#awf_field-106493013').val(data.ip); //This does not work
                   }
              });
                 }());


           jQuery('#awf_field-106493014').val(date.toString()); //This works properly
          if(tid != null){
           jQuery('#awf_field-106493015').val(tid.toString()); //This works properly
          }else{
            jQuery('#awf_field-106493015').val("nulltid"); //This works properly
          }

        });


</script>
```

I've also tried to make the call and replacement with `jQuery.get` and the replacement with `document.getElementById`. All other fields are replaced except for this one IP field and, as the comment in the code says, the IP is even properly printed into the console before it's dropped while trying to be replaced.

I've also tried changing `async` from `false` to `true`, but this also did not work.

I have no idea why this is behaving how it is and would like some assistance.

Thanks!

Comment: console log `console.log(typeof data.ip);` to see what it is. My guess is it is may be an object of some type.

Comment: You might also consider cleaning up the HTML element.  The `name` attribute has a space in it, which I don't think is valid, and the blur and focus events seems kinda nonsensical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out this particular api was returning some sort of weird json object, after reading their documentation I changed `https://api.ipify.org/?format=json` to `https://api.ipify.org/` and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you are unable to retrieve the ip address to the text box with id "awf_field-106493013" ?

If yes, your code works fine for me.

https://jsfiddle.net/7yqrk1hL/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-106493013">ipaddress:</label>
    <div class="af-textWrap"><input type="text" id="awf_field-106493013" class="text" name="custom ipaddress" value=""
            onfocus=" if (this.value == '') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value='';} "
            tabindex="503" /></div>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            (function () {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'https://api.ipify.org/?format=json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        //callback
                        console.log(data.ip) //This works properly;
                        jQuery('#awf_field-106493013').val(data.ip); //This does not work
                    }
                });
            }());


            jQuery('#awf_field-106493014').val(date.toString()); //This works properly
            if (tid != null) {
                jQuery('#awf_field-106493015').val(tid.toString()); //This works properly
            } else {
                jQuery('#awf_field-106493015').val("nulltid"); //This works properly
            }

        });


    </script>
</body>

</html>
```